# Create a JavaFX primary stage inside a normal Java application

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, stage

I have a launcher and a JavaFX class. The launcher creates a class called JavaFXApplication1. The JavaFXApplication contains the whole JavaFX code (Just a little example in this case) and should setup a window with one primary stage.

The launcher has the static main entry point - but I read that JavaFX doesn't really use this entry point. This explains my console output (See the end of the post)

I don't know if this is possible (Launcher create a JavaFX window - the entry point is **not** in the presentation class itself) . I don't want to use a preloader (I think preloaders are just for heavy loads during startup), because the launcher represents the whole program as one object (Presentation, business and persistence - a 3 layer program). The entry point should be outside the presentation class (in this example in the launcher class)

The following example does work. But for me it is like a piece of "black magic"

Here is my code

Launcher:

```
package javafxapplication1;

public class Launcher
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("main()");

        // Do some stuff and then create the UI class

        JavaFXApplication1 client = new JavaFXApplication1();
        client.caller(args);
    }
}
```

JavaFXApplication1:

```
package javafxapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application
{ 
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        System.out.println("start()");
        primaryStage.setTitle("I am a JavaFX app");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void caller(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("caller()");
        launch(args);
    }
    /* We call the main function from the client
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }*/
}
```

And the output for the program is:

```
start()
```

Is there a way to create such an application ? Thank you

Comment: Main method is not used really, this is a feature of JFX 8.0: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27808 OR https://jbs.oracle.com/bugs/browse/JDK-8001533

Comment: Thank you for the tip: The second answer is: 2) Create a separate Main class that doesn't extend from javafx.application.Application and have that call into the launcher (only if you really cannot do what you need to do some other way).

How does he mean this ? Is this not my case ? Sadly, I cannot reach your second link (down for me)

Comment: @AlexanderKirov Related to this article http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-November/012382.html and your hint I see the problem. But I am locking for a way to solve it (if possible)

Comment: I tried to create a simple Java Application (not a JavaFX application, and everything works as you wish : main() caller() start(). (JDK8 b76, NetBeans 7.3beta2)

Comment: Hmm..then I make a mistake. I create a java project, add a java class (with a main method) and javafx class (extends Application) to the project. Netbeans cannot find the javafx packages (Problem occurs under Kubuntu with Oracle JDK7 and Windows 7, also Oracle JDK 7). JavaFX is enabled in the plattform profile.

Comment: Ok...missing compile time libraries. I added the same from a JavaFX project and now it works ;) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem is to create a java project and not a JavaFX project. After this you can add a JavaFX main class and write a method (call launch() ).

Maybe you have to add the compile-time libraries deploy.jar, javaws.jar, jfxrt.jar and plugin.jar from the /jdk_*/jre/lib directory

Comment: Comment on this issue. If you use a usual JavaApplication, a standart packager will be used, and main method will be called. If you create a JavaFX application - a javafxpackager will be used and a main method will be ignored, a class extending Application, will be called via start(..) method. That was verified with developers architect.

Comment: Comment on the code in the question : you should use  "Application.launch(JavaFXApplication.class, args)" instead of creating new instance, and its method call, because a new instance creating will be ignored.

Comment: And the last thing to say, you shouldn't use a main method, if you want your application to be distributed with an applet or web start.

Answer (score 1):

I written a post at 
[Running JavaFX Application instance in the main method of a class – MacDevign](https://macdevign.wordpress.com/2014/03/27/running-javafx-application-instance-in-the-main-method-of-a-class/)

Could it be what you looking for ?

The code is quite long hence it is better to refer to the post however the usage is simple. Take note that the init and stop method do not use launcher thread so use it with care.

The purpose is to run a dummy javafx application on your main method of your class for quick testing/experimenting purpose.

To use this, just add the following in the main method using lambda, or alternatively you can use anonymous inner class style.

```
// using the start method of Application class
Utility.launchApp((app, stage) -> {
    // javafx code
}, arArgs);
```

Comment: Please do not provide link-only answers.  At least include a summary of the proposed solution in case the provide link stops working.